# Auto create radio button from the database in java

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I working on the voting system for my university project. I have saved some data in the database. How to automatically create radio buttons, and rename the buttons to the name saved in the database.
For example, if there are 4 names in the database, then there should be automatic created 4 radio buttons with the name.

Answer (score 1):

Here are logical steps:

1. You get ResultSet from database
2. while(ResultSet.next())
3. create new RadioButton
4. String valueFromDatabase = ResultSet.getString("name of column from database");
5. RadioButton.setText(valueFromDatabase)
6. Grid or Scene or whatever you using to show form .addElement(RadioButton)

edit: I added code. Just insted of String[] array use ResultSet.

```
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();

    String[] valuesFromDatabase = new String[]{"radio button name 1", "radio button name 2", "radio button name 3", "radio button name 4"};

    int row = 0;
    for (String valueFromDatabase : valuesFromDatabase) {
      RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton();
      radioButton.setText(valueFromDatabase);
      grid.add(radioButton, 0, row);
      row++;
    }
```